# Why is the print statement in the class executed when an object isn't even created?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

When I run the code below the output is "hello".

However, the `print` statement is part of the class `pl`, and i never created an instance of the class `pl`, so why is the `print` statement being executed?

```
class pl:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.aa=a
        self.bb=b
    print("hello")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Class bodies (even nested class bodies) are executed at import time (as opposed to functions or methods).

Demo script:

```
class Upper:
    print('Upper')
    class Mid:
        print('Mid')
    def method(self):
        class Low:
            print('Low')
        print('method')
```

Output:

```
$ python3
>>> import demo
Upper
Mid
```

Comment: Thanks! Does 'def method(self):' belong to class Mid or class Upper? Based on indentation i would say it belongs to upper, but it's below/within Mid so I'm confused. Also am I correct in saying that print('method') doesn't belong to class Low?

Comment: @user3124200 `method` is an attribute of the class `Upper`. `print('method')` is a print statement executed in the body of `method`, not in the body of `Low`. You can work this out by looking at the indentation levels.

Comment: @timegb  Thanks! I  am confused on the following point though:  1) print('Upper') is executed as part of the Upper class and then 2) print('Mid') is executed as part of the Mid class and then 3)  method is an attribute of the class upper. I'm confused at how the code jumps around from having statements belong to the upper class, then the mid class, and then the upper class again. Shouldn't  everything defined within one class first & then within a nested  class, and then within another sub class etc. How would you express the above code if python used curly brackets rather than indentation?

Comment: @user3124200 does [this](https://pastebin.com/6AMzVCnG) pseudo-code help?